# How can I install jsawk to node and run with shelljs on Windows?

Tags: json, node.js, shell, awk, msysgit

js gurus on *windows*,

I send some curl request via shelljs and get some JSON back.

example JS-Code

```
var sh = require('shelljs');
sh.exec('curl -H "Accept: application/vnd.github.v3.text-match+json" \\ ' +
          'https://api.github.com/repos/jquery/jquery/tags ',
          {silent:true}).output;
```

Now, I would like to parse JSON with jsawk. My thoughts are right similar like [Bash shell extract object from json file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22316714/2199721) and [How to parse json with shell scripting](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22678713/2199721).

**My Question** is how can I install jsawk inside of node_modules folder structur (maybe .bin folder) and run as additional statement at `sh.exec`?

Has somebody an idea?

Another way might be to `grep` and `awk` the JSON data. I want to check the `name` properties, find correct version number (e.g. 2.1.1) and call `zipball_url`. But I'm not good as should to do this via shell basics.

Best, Ronn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use npm:

```
npm install jsawk
```

It auto install jsawk in node_modules and then you can use it in your script:

```
var jsawk = require('jsawk');
```

But why are you using curl from shell, there are better ways to get http data, the basic is http request

```
var https = require('https');
var options = {
  host: 'api.github.com',
  path: '/repos/jquery/jquery/tags',
  port: 443,
  method: 'GET',
  headers: {'User-Agent': 'nodejstestagent'}
};

var req = https.get(options, function(res) {
  console.log('STATUS: ' + res.statusCode);
  console.log('HEADERS: ' + JSON.stringify(res.headers));

  // Buffer the body entirely for processing as a whole.
  var bodyChunks = [];
  res.on('data', function(chunk) {
    // You can process streamed parts here...
    bodyChunks.push(chunk);
  }).on('end', function() {
    var body = Buffer.concat(bodyChunks);
    var jsonResponse = JSON.parse( body) ;
    console.log( JSON.stringify( jsonResponse,null,3 ));
  })
});

req.on('error', function(e) {
  console.log('ERROR: ' + e.message);
});
```

Will output something like this:

```
[
   {
      "name": "2.1.1-rc2",
      "zipball_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/jquery/jquery/zipball/2.1.1-rc2",
      "tarball_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/jquery/jquery/tarball/2.1.1-rc2",
      "commit": {
         "sha": "c2fdcaaacd4d7f8479b2196525330c1738e30cd3",
         "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/jquery/jquery/commits/c2fdcaaacd4d7f8479b2196525330c1738e30cd3"
      }
   },
   {
      "name": "2.1.1-rc1",
      "zipball_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/jquery/jquery/zipball/2.1.1-rc1",
      "tarball_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/jquery/jquery/tarball/2.1.1-rc1",
      "commit": {
         "sha": "6ba4c8def1f9b0d03c5e8de1d64a78ae36646fb6",
         "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/jquery/jquery/commits/6ba4c8def1f9b0d03c5e8de1d64a78ae36646fb6"
      }
   },
```

Updated for https and github rule for User-Agent

Comment: Oui, totally other way that is working! Nice job, thanks. I'll focus on your advice. I leave this question open 'cause _'how to run jsawk as statement at shell command via shell.js'_ is still not solved.

Comment: Glad to help! about jsawk, it's a bit tricky, because windows does not recognize #!/path/to/interpretor like in linux, hence you can't run directly node_modules\jsawk\bin\jsawk witout some tweaks in windows variables, here is a similar issues with php http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16646003/windows-equivalent-to-usr-bin-php

Comment: Set an env var is a possible way to work with jsawk. It can be unhandy for non-technical user or a automated build maschine. Someone has to register this variable manually.