# Run PHP script with command line globally on win10

Tags: php, windows, command-line-interface

How to run a PHP script with command line globally, like:

```
update var1=abc var2 var3=def
```

"Update" located in fact: "C:\Localhost\Scripts\Update.php"

Many sources suggest this as:

```
php update.php var1=abc var2 var3=def
```

Shortly: How to run a PHP script as if it was a registered executable?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Windows equivalent to #!/usr/bin/php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16646003/windows-equivalent-to-usr-bin-php). In particular, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16651493/283366)

Comment: Also see http://php.net/manual/install.windows.legacy.index.php#install.windows.legacy.commandline

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally solved it:

-Create a .bat file where your php file in, it contains:

```
@ECHO OFF
php %~dp0/update.php %*
```

-And save it as "update.bat"
-Add the directory name into "Path" in "Environment Variables"

Now you can write "update var1=abc var2 var3=def" freely in command prompt!

Answer (score 1):

> **Disclaimer:** I've written this answer for Linux/Ubuntu, I'm not sure if it'll work for Windows (the OP updated the question's requirements).

---

So, this *is* possible, the way I've described here basically just has a global bash script call a PHP file. Here's the steps:

1. Make a new bash script:

   ```
   #!/usr/bin/env bash
   php /path/to/yourphpfile.php
   ```
2. Change the file executable: `chmod +x /path/to/yourbashscript`
3. Copy the bash script into `/usr/local/bin/`: `sudo cp /path/to/yourbashscript /usr/local/bin/`
4. Open a new terminal, then run `yourbashscript` (or whatever you named it).

And voila! A globally available PHP script!

Comment: I forgot to mention but my OS is win10, does it matter?

Comment: @Digerkam Hmm, I'm not sure. I'd written this answer for Linux/Ubuntu, but if it works for Windows 10 then great :) I'll update my answer if I find a way specifically for Windows.

Comment: In Windows you can add an environment variable to point to a path or file. Google environment variables windows to find out more. Then use: php %yourNewPath%

Comment: @siggi_pop I understand, but it looks very dirty: php %update%... Is there any way to remove percentage or "php" prefix?

Comment: It should be possible without the percentage symbol. The PHP prefix is necessary, it's the global alias for php.exe. what you could do is type PHP + enter once to open the PHP cli and from there you could use PHP command without the prefix.